# Mapping Mouse Position to Rotation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I want to write a simple foosball game in unity. To rotate the players I am mapping my mouse movement to the rotation of the players:

```
float mod = (Input.mousePosition.x - RotationSpeed) * RotationSpeed;
rb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3((90 - mod) , 90, 90);
```

with mod being a delta to my mouse position. However by doing so I can't kick the ball as I teleport through it by setting the exakt angle. So my question is: how to map the rotation in a way that I actually am able to apply force to the ball, so that it can be shot?

Edit more information:
By moving my mouse to the left, my players rotate clockwise. E.g. my mouse is at x position 300 , then the rotation of the player will be set to 300 times a step (here called "Rotation Speed"). Counterclockwise in the other direction. As in a typical foosball game I want to kick the ball by flinging my mouse to one of the directions. However the ball gets stuck / does not move much when they collide. The reason for this is probably, that by setting the euler Angle directly, the players "teleport" through the ball and don't kick it back. So I need some kind of an instant smooth motion to where my mouse is.

Comment: Please add some more context. What does your formula for `mod` do? What does *I can't kick the ball as I teleport through it by setting the exakt angle* mean? How do you want the controls to behave and what do you get with your current solution?

Comment: I added a bit of information, hope that clears a bit

Comment: If you want to use the physics engine, it is a good idea to let the player only control forces that you add to the bodies and let the forces cause the rotations, collisions, etc.

Comment: Well, yes that is what we thought too. So it is kinda hard to use forces to set to a specific position. Our best approach up to now is to use on collide and add the speed to the ball. But somehow it does not feel right this way